# Firefox devtools not showing POST body

Tags: firefox, graphql, firefox-developer-tools

I'm working in an Angular project integrating with AWS using graphql. When using Chrome, I can see the request (POST) payload of the query I'm running in the "Request Payload" section. But in firefox devtools, I can't. Under the request tab when inspecting a XHR, it says "No parameters for this request". 
Strange thing in that when in firefox I try to copy the request using "Copy as Fetch" or "Copy as Curl" it doesn't copy the payload either.

The request is executed correctly returning the expected data.

So, I can't use firefox for debugging this.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Firefox, though if possible you should provide a small test case so people can reproduce the issue. In any case, you should make sure you have the latest Firefox version installed (which is currently 77.0.1).